# Querying for URL string in SQLite 3 database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, url, special-characters

I am writing in my first Android application and using an SQLite database to store off data on several tables.  One of my tables contains the URLs of a bunch of pages that correspond to a certain search.

Using a string field in my database, I am easily able to store off the html (in the form html://mysite.org/blah/blah.htm or *.jpg depending on what I'm doing).  These URLs are easily retrievable from the database as well.

However, in order to be more efficient, I only want to parse and add these URLs one time.  I want to be able to search the table for the URL and only parse and add it if the URL doesn't already exist.  The problem is the special characters (for sure the colon and the period) are causing issues since they are query characters.  I have tried using brackets({}), surrounding the URL in the query with single quotes(') and even tried backslash.

Is there something I am missing here to be able to query:
SELECT * from TABLE WHERE url="http://*.htm" ?

Additionally, is this the best way to store a URL to a database?  The URLs I am dealing with are sometimes search URLs with values populated from a search form, so they may have special characters in them (think Craigslist searches)?

Any direction is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation of the `LIKE` operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like); your query should look like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE url LIKE 'http://%.htm'
```

Furthermore, it is possible that your search strings contains `%` or `_` characters, so you should use the `ESCAPE` clause.

To ensure that special characters like `'` do not trip you up when constructing an SQL command, use parameters:

```
String searchPattern = "http://%.htm%";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE url LIKE ?",
                       new String[] { searchPattern });
```